# Building a 2D Array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to build a 2D array in javascript, but not having much success. I'm pulling some data from a DB and I then want to combine some fields into a 2D array in order to use it elsewhere in the code. Ideally what I want to end up with is:

```
mapLocs = [
    ['name a','location a',1],
    ['name b','location b',2],
    ['name c','location c',3]
]
```

here is the code I am using to build the `mapLocs` array:

```
    for(i = 0;i < phtLen;i++){
        var x = i + 1;
        var myLocs = new Array(myPhotogs[i].phtName,myPhotogs[i].phtLoc,x);
        console.log(myLocs);
        mapLocs[i] = new Array(myLocs);
        }
    }
```

which is pretty much the method that I've gathered from reading similar problems here. The `console.log()` outputs an array consisting of the three elements I want, but if I try to access `mapLocs` it doesn't seem to consist of three arrays as I would have expected, but of three elements each of which is made up of the three elements in the `myLoc` array if that makes sense? So:

```
console.log(mapLocs[0][0]); // Joe Bloggs, SW1A 1AA, 1
```

where I was expecting just 'Joe Bloggs' and

```
console.logs(mapLocs[0][1]); // undefined
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing `mapLocs[i] = new Array(myLocs);` to `mapLocs[i] = myLocs;`

Comment: You can also try `mapLocs[i] = [myPhotogs[i].phtName,myPhotogs[i].phtLoc,x+1]`

Comment: Ah! Brilliant, that works a treat! Thank you so much!

Comment: Your code never declares `mapLocs`.  Prior to the `for` loop, you need something like: `var mapLocs = [];`. In what you have provided, you also have an extra `}` which, in addition, does not match your indenting.

Comment: This was just a snippet of the code which I cut and pasted. mapLocs is actually declared elsewhere, and the extra } was copied in error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explicit new Array() constructor does not take an array and make a new array identical to the argument array, but takes a list of arguments that you wish to be contained within the new array. So in the line

```
mapLocs[i] = new Array(myLocs)
```

mapLocs[i] is actually being set to

```
[[Joe Bloggs, SW1A 1AA, 1]]
```

Instead, you could say

```
mapLocs[i] = myLocs.slice()
```

which will clone myLocs and place it at index i in mapLocs, resulting in the output you want.

Comment: I've accepted this as correct because it is correct (I tried it out), though I've actually gone with the suggestion in the first comment under my original post.

Comment: Thanks anyways! Glad you found your answer.